# Как хранить логин/пароль локально в .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Всем привет! Знаю, что вопрос избитый и ответ: "пароли хранить нельзя". Но все же возникала такая необходимость.

**Задача:**

Приложение на Avalonia UI (C#/.Net Core) для Windows/Linux для взаимодействия с Redmine. Для работы с Redmine используется [redmine-net-api](https://github.com/zapadi/redmine-net-api). Вход по логину/паролю.

**Должно обеспечиваться:**

При первом запуске запрос логина/пароля, при последующих автоматический вход, а также смена логина/пароля для входа в настройках.

**Необходимо (достаточно)**:

Автоматический вход выполняется только для того пользователя, который указал логин/пароль. Т.е. другой пользователь при запуске приложения на той же машине не авторизуется в RM под ранее указанными данными другого пользователя. Также при копировании файлов приложения получившего логин/пароль на другую машину - взаимодействие с RM было не возможно.

**Варианты:**

Для Windows есть решение: [Retrieve credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp)
, но хотелось обеспечить работу приложения на других ОС (хотя бы linux).

Также была идея использовать примерно такое решение: [Data Encryption And Decryption in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f8fa6c/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-C-Sharp/). Но в таком случае возникает проблема хранения ключа.

Также была идея использовать решение выше, а ключ собирать на лету из уникальных данных машины и пользователя, но как я понял в .NET Core нет универсального решения получения таких данных на разных ОС.

Может кто что подскажет?

Comment: В Windows есть специально для этого DPAPI, в Linux наверное тоже что-то есть.

Comment: @aepot, да, я в вариантах это указал, но так и не нашел аналога для linux

Comment: Не знаю, тогда может токен получать от сервера после авторизации и его хранить и использовать для подключения.

Comment: Не вариант. Хранение токена позволит любому пользователю подключаться к РМ под чужими данными + использую sdk для rm api, там токен не получить

Comment: В смысле любому? А как тогда браузер работает? Любой пользователь может стянуть токен и подключиться куда угодно? Токен может быть привязан к текущему юзеру, например, можно у сервера узнать, к какому юзеру (локальному) привязан токен и инвалидировать, если не совпало, и так далее, на что фантазии хватит. :) Но самое главное, что позволяет сделать токен - сохранить креды юзера в секрете.

Comment: И да, как вы верно подметили, универсального решения для всех операционок нет и не будет. Кстати, что мешает в линуксах записать данные в файл на диск с правами 600? Тогда прочитать его сможет только текущий юзер и root, шифрантуть можно только чисто для приличия, а не для безопасности. В любом случае для авторизации хэш пароля передается, в качестве сессии получается токен, его и хранить.

Comment: @aepot браузер же идентифицирует пользователя ОС чтобы "не путать" данные или я не прав? О каком сервере и токене идет речь? Приложение - клиент RM и должно взаимодействовать только с RM через SDK по логину и паролю. В Windows как раз для этого есть механизм хранения учетных данных.

Comment: В .Net Core для взаимодействия с ОС как оказалось есть только Windows/UWP библиотеки. Под другие ОС ничего не могу найти.

Comment: Просто запишите креды в файл с правами 600, и другие пользователи не смгут его прочитать.

Comment: @aepot, думаю как вариант генерировать ключ-пароль симметричного шифрования и хранить его в файле с правами 600, а пароль + ID юзера в ОС (для сопоставления) в зашифрованном виде хранить а appstate. Так хоть какая-то "безопасность". Спасибо за наводку)